# Is a bridge defense easier if the values are about equally distributed?

Tags: bridge

The conventional wisdom is that a bridge declaration for game will have about a 50-50 chance of success if declarer has about 25 high card points, and the defense has 15. That's "all other things being equal."

But a 24 point declaration might well succeed if they are divided about equally between declarer and dummy, because of good "transportation," while a 26 point declaration divided 22 points and 4 might fail because of bad transportation.

Does a similar line of reasoning hold on defense? If one defender has made an opening bid or takeout double, the implication is that defender holds most of the defensive values, (and this fact is known to declarer). Is that a disadvantage? Or are there offsetting advantages, such as the information being made available to the other defender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the defensive values split between the hands is better for the defense for the same reason as declarer, but the advantage is not as strong for defenders as for declarers. This is because defenders are more likely to choose the wrong suit to work on as they have less information about their combined strength, and less coordination. For example, it's more difficult for one defender to lead clubs and the other defender to switch to spades to get the entry to partner's hand, than it is for declarer to lead up to dummy's clubs, and then switch to a spade to get back to declarer's hand.

Comment: The value of having one person making most of the decisions rather than guessing what partner wants is difficult to evaluate, but gets less as the skill of the partnership improves.

Answer (score 2):

Having the bulk of the defensive values is so well known to be a liability that it has its own term in the bridge lexicon - *end-played at trick 1*.

What possible reason do you have for thinking otherwise? There is no fundamental difference between the card play as Declarer or Defender, which is why throw-ins, squeezes and end-plays work equally well for both sides..